# Power line fonts not displaying in oh-my-zsh

Tags: vim, zsh, iterm2, powerline

Using Iterm2, in my Oh-My-Zsh preferences I am using `Menlo for Powerline` however the bars are not appearing as they should be - I get big white arrows.

[image: Oh-My-Zsh terminal]

Has anyone had any experience of this and know what could be the cause?

Comment: You didn't even say what's your terminal emulator.

Comment: Judging from the screenshot, you seem to be using a dated version of iTerm2 (you might be using the latest stable, but latest stable *is* very old). Could you try the latest beta or nightly? https://iterm2.com/downloads.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer was not down to Powerline fonts but due to having the contrast turned up in Iterm2! When I set that to nothing it worked perfectly.